# Find first argument in map

Tags: f#

I keep practicing my F# skills on Project Euler. While doing problem 19 (a drastic anticlimax after the cool [problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18)) I found myself in need of performing a modulo 7 operation on a list of numbers. I tried this:

```
List.map ((%) 7)
```

And ended up with the wrong list of numbers. That's because `List.map` binds the second argument, so instead of calculation n%7 it ended up calculating 7%n . Is there a way to make `List.map` bind the first argument, or a standard way of flipping the two arguments?

I know I can use a `fun n->n%7` instead of `(%) 7`, but I was hoping for a shorter solution.

Comment: A side note: Problem 19 can be beautifully solved in pure functional manner using **very** limited math -
just `+ 1`. To see how you may check [this F# snippet](http://fssnip.net/88).

Comment: It's about as long as the solution to problem 18...

Comment: (editorial) "I know I can use a `fun n->n%7` instead of `(%) 7`, but I was hoping for a shorter solution."  This is a disease that seems common among Haskellers, the desire to find esoteric language features or library functions that enable you to shave three characters off your code.  I cannot fathom this mindset.

Comment: I guess I should be flattered because you called ma a Haskeller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `flip` for this purpose:

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Core
module Operators =
    let flip f x y = f y x
```

This is a rather common way of doing this in functional programming languages. For example, Haskell also has a `flip` function [in its Prelude](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/flip_f.html).

Comment: I was hoping something like this was already defined. Thanks, I added it. Turns out it's too early to accept an answer. I'll accept later.

Comment: You ought to make it `inline` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Others already pointed out that this can be done by defining a `flip` function from Haskell. However, I would recommend writing the code explicitly using lambda function or using list comprehensions (which is shorter and avoids explicit lambdas):

```
inputs |> List.map (fun n-> n % 7)
[ for n in inputs -> n % 7 ]
```

It might be a good idea to define a helper function `moduloBy` that behaves like `%` with flipped arguments:

```
let moduloBy n input = input % n
inputs |> List.map (moduloBy 7)
```

The reason is **readability**. Although Euler problems are toy examples, it is important to write code that is easy to understand. This is even more important in F# where it is fairly easy to write code that is really hard to understand. I think you'll agree that reading the above snippets is easier than reading (and, the solution using `flip` isn't significantly shorter either):

```
inputs |> List.map ((flip (%)) 7)
```

Comment: One of the few drawbacks of FP--makes it possible to write some truly hard to understand code.

Comment: Once you get used to `flip`, it should be clearer than `fun n->n%7`. It's certainly takes less getting used to than fold...

Comment: @zmbq I don't think that point-free style can be clearer than explicit lambda, with the exception of simple partial application or maybe function composition. If you're a skilled functional programmer working in a team of Haskell programmers, then it will be fine, but otherwise I'd prefer another option.

Answer (score 2):

The `flip` function:

```
let inline flip f a b = f b a
```

is usually used for this task. Now you can pass `flip (%) 7` directly to `List.map`.

This is called point-free style which is popular in Haskell but not so common in F# community. The problem is that it could make programs difficult to read and hard to maintain in many cases.